# how to I make the code to print the numbers given and and show what it equals

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: need help to figure out how to make the output run to show something like this 4+6=10 encluding -,*,divde]

I tried to make just add print(a+b) and I only got what it equals I don't know what to do I can't find it or look for it online.

Comment: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: do you want this? **print(f"{a}+{b}={a+b}")**

Comment: this is what I have to do  but I don't understand it

Comment: Create code that will evaluate all 4 basic math functions (addition, subtraction, division, multiplication) and then output each of the variables with the math function being performed followed by the result of the math operation.

Comment: 3 + 4 = 7
3 - 4 = -1
3 / 4 = 0.75
3 x 4 = 12

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up printing a string vs. printing an expression.

Printing a string like `print('hello world')` will print the literal message because you've indicated it's a string with quotes.

However, if you provide an expression like `print(a+b)`, it will evaluate that expression (calculate the math) and then print the string representation of that evaluation.

Now, what you want is actually a mix of both, you want to print a string that has certain parts replaced with an expression. This can be done by "adding" strings and expressions together like so:

`print(a + '+' + b + '=' + (a+b))`

Notice the difference between `+` without quotes and `'+'` with quotes. The first is the addition operator, the second is the literal plus character. Let's break down how the print statement parses this. Let's say we have `a = 5` and `b = 3`. First, we evaluate all the expressions:

`print(5 + '+' + 3 + '=' + 8)`

Now, we have to add a combination of numbers with strings. The `+` operator acts differently depending on context, but here it will simply convert everything into a string and then "add" them together like letters or words. Now it becomes something like:

`print('5' + '+' + '3' + '=' + '8')`

Notice how each number is now a string by the surrounding quotes. This parses to:

`print('5+3=8')`

which prints the literal `5+3=8`

Comment: thanks man I am I got the work done I am teaching myself and I have never worked on python never in my life.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like that:

```
a = int(input("Give me a number man: "))
b = int(input("Give me another number: "))
print(f'print({a} + {b}) = {a + b}')
print(f'print({a} - {b}) = {a - b}')
print(f'print({a} * {b}) = {a * b}')
print(f'print({a} // {b}) = {a // b}')
print("Look at all those maths!")
```

Output

```
Give me a number man: 3
Give me another number: 2
print(3 + 2) = 5
print(3 - 2) = 1
print(3 * 2) = 6
print(3 // 2) = 1
Look at all those maths!
```

Comment: If f-strings are a little too much for a newbie, `print(a, '+', b, '=', a + b)` will do the trick (`print` implicitly inserts spaces between positional arguments).

Comment: thanks I am just learning and I am having a hard time